# What is the best way to save multiple -repeated- inputs from html page

Tags: php, mysql

The PHP code in the admin page prints all the details of an album in a table. all of details but the id are changeable.

```
$sql = "SELECT `id`, `name`, `desc`, `url`, `order`, `hidden` FROM `albums` ORDER by albums.order asc";
    $result = $con->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td>"."<input type='text' placeholder='order' value='".$row['order']."' size=2 /></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' placeholder='Name' value='".$row['name']."'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='text' placeholder='description'  value='".$row['desc']."'/></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='checkbox'";if($row['hidden']==1)echo "checked"; 
    echo"></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

The code above is between the table tags, and it prints all the albums in the database.

What I want to do is to make a submit button to save all the changes in the albums details that the admin would make.

it would be not very efficient to define a field for each album. I want a better way to save the changes.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass multiple values as an array if you name the input field like `somefield[]`. On the PHP side this will give you an array `somefield` which contains one entry for each input element of the same name.

In your case, you'd use for example

```
echo "<td>"."<input type='text' placeholder='order' name='orders[]' value='".$row['order']."' size=2 /></td>";
```

and receive all the form's order values as a single array named "orders".